# How to create a shortkey for "Replace image" in "UV/Image editor"?

Tags: interface, customization, image, shortcut

In the **UV/Image editor**, in the **Image** Menu, every option such as **Reload image** has a shortcut, except for **Replace image**.
So I've tried to add a shortcut in the preferences, right under where I found "Reload Image" shortcut, then saved the user settings. All was done just as the manual said, but it is not working.
How can I add this shortcut?

Comment: You need to make sure the command isn't already used somewhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add the new shortcut in *User preferences > Input* scroll down to :

[image]

click Add New , set up your shortcut as follows :

[image]

***NOTE:*** the shortcut name 'Replace Image' will come up automatically

- Save your preferences and now you can use your new shortcut

---

To know what to type for the shortcuts use the tooltips :

[image]

Comment: @elmentor If this solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. This is done by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. Doing this will let future users with the same problem know that this solved the issue.

Comment: This was flagged as low quality. I agree to a degree, but not enough to recommend deletion, though I think an explanation on how to access the setting in the image would be in order.

Comment: @SixthOfFour sorry ,the answer was too specific for the question as I assumed he already knows where to go I will see what i can add

Comment: i appreciate your time helping me. this is my first time on the forum here. i have another similar question , i will start a new topic for that!